# Change outerHTML in javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to change the outerHTML and this is what I do:

```
$(data.description)[0].outerHTML = $(data.description)[0].outerHTML.replace('red', 'black');
```

The value is:

```
$(data.description)[0].outerHTML: "<p style="color: red;">desc1</p>"
```

and it doesn't get changed. How to change it?

data.description has this value:

```
<p style="color: red;">desc1</p><p style="color: red;">desc2</p>
```

And I want only $(data.description)[0] changed.

Here is my whole code:

```
var ingsLines = $(data.description);
for (var i =0; i < ingsLines.length; i++) {
    if (someCondition) {
        $(data.description).eq(i).css('color', 'black');
    }
}
try{$('#myTextarea').html(data.description);}catch(err){}
```

And the code changes the value, it puts black instead of red, but data.description stays with red.

Comment: Not, it's read-only. Use jQuery's `replaceWith` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to change the color property of the first element, you can use `css` and `eq`  methods:

```
$(data.description).eq(0).css('color', 'black');
```

Comment: I suppose OP wanted to change all occurrences, not just the color in the style.

Comment: @Srcee It depends on whether you append the markup or not, this doesn't change the property of your data object, can you provide a demo on http://jsfiddle.net?

Comment: Ok can you please see my edited question again. Your code changes the color, but it still doesn't work - the text in my textarea stays red.

Comment: @Srcee The color of text of textarea remains red because you cannot append an element to it, it only accepts text content.

Comment: So how can I convert element to text?

Comment: @Srcee Create a jQuery object and then use `text` method, `$(object).text()` or if you want to add the element as text you can use `val` method `$('textarea').val(data.description)`

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
$(data.description).replaceWith(function(){
    return this.outerHTML.replace('red', 'black')
});
```

[Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/NP8EY/)

If you want to change only first one, you may use this :

```
$(data.description).eq(0).replaceWith(function(){
    return this.outerHTML.replace('red', 'black')
});
```

Comment: @dystroy But you code changes the color of the whole data.description, I want it to change only the line with [i] index

Comment: And then do I need to call this replaceWith method somehow?

Comment: Ok can you please see my edited question again. Your code changes the color, but it still doesn't work - the text in my textarea stays red.